# What are the equivalent amounts of these sweeteners?

Tags: sweeteners

I've been looking into using one of/some combination of the following:

- Powdered sucralose,
- Sucralose liquid,
- Powdered stevia extract,
- Liquid stevia extract,
- Erythritol

I'd like to know which one/combination is the most economical for sweetening recipes, and I know prices can vary, so what are the equivalent amounts of each?

Comment: So is your question actually what the equivalent amounts are? Prices can vary a lot, so I'm not sure how useful it is for people to just tell you which seems to be cheapest from where they're sitting.

Comment: Do you think the cheapest will give you an acceptable flavor profile? The cheapest sweetener combo could possibly not taste well.

Comment: Let's not have a health discussion here, y'all. Head to [chat] if you have anything to say about it; any health-related comments here will be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

I had always wanted an "artificial" sweetener that worked for me, but I have always been extremely sensitive to them. Not that they give me headaches or anything like that, I just find them vile. The aftertaste especially was just nasty to me.

Then one day I was offered a water with a couple of drops of flavoring. It was like drinking lemonade. Sugar sweetened lemonade! Well, it obviously wasn't sugar sweetened, because that would have taken more than a couple of drops. I'm a naturally curious food nerd, so I read the label of the drops. The drops were the brand name Dasani, and the sweeteners were sucralose and acesulfame potassium (Ace K). I had never heard of Ace K, and I already knew I didn't like sucralose (alone). This was not boding well, but I was intrigued. So, I used every bit of Google-fu that I had (and a lot that I didn't) to learn this:

Pure sucralose is about 600 times as sweet as sugar (by weight). Ace K is about 200 times as sweet as sugar (also by weight). Combine them, and they become "sweeter than the sum of their parts". This is not within the scope of your question, but I will tell you this too (also borne out by my lengthy research): Ace K works beautifully to wipeout the aftertaste that other artificial sweeteners tend to have, particularly sucralose and aspartame (nutrasweet). So, by combining Ace K and another sweetener (I recommend sucralose), you get two benefits. Number one, it takes less of each to sweeten whatever it is you're trying to sweeten, and number two, you knockout the aftertaste of the sweeteners.

So, to get started, you need a gram scale (they're not just for chemists and drug dealers):

[This one is mine, $10](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0012LOQUQ)

You also need [pure sucralose, 50 grams lasted me over two years, $19, 100 grams is only $3 more](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CCXMBC8)

and

[Ace K, the smallest amount on Amazon might last a lifetime, 1 pound, $13](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BPY9TGG)

Use the gram scale and mix the sweeteners 50/50 by weight. Pull your shirt over your mouth and nose or wear a mask to mix them, otherwise you will taste sweet for days. A scant 1/8 teaspoon of the combo will sweeten an entire double-strength, 12 cup pot of coffee (which I mix with milk to create iced coffee). You can also bake with it. It's amazing stuff. To me (artificial sweetener phobic), it's indistinguishable from sugar.

**EDIT:** Yoplait has recently started advertising that their light yogurt is aspartame free. What are they using instead? Ace K and sucralose.

Comment: Interesting, I'll certainly look into it. Do you happen to know how much of this sweetener mix is the "equivalent" to a cup(or any other amount) of plain sugar? You give the example of a 12 cup pot of coffee but that's kinda vague.

Comment: Have you experimented with Stevia and Ace K combinations?

Comment: Only minimally. I find Stevia difficult to choke down, so I only tested it a few times with Ace K because I didn't want to do it again. I didn't see the same effect with Ace K and Stevia that was apparent with Ace K and sucralose or NutraSweet.

Comment: @user2649681 Well, considering the fact that a scant 1/8 teaspoon sweetens what is basically 24 cups of coffee, I think you could start with that as equivalent to 3/4 cups of sugar.

Comment: @user2649681 I do recommend using a scale (a gram scale like the one in the answer) instead of volumetric measurement at least until you know what you're doing. A very tiny difference (volumetrically) can make a huge difference as far as taste.

Comment: @user2649681 In that case (using the scale), 400 parts to 1 is going to be pretty close after you mix the two sweeteners equally by weight. Volumetrically that won't seem right, but sugar is a lot heavier by volume than sucralose or Ace K.

Comment: Removing health stuff here too. Feel free to head to [chat] if you want to talk about it!